# 8080 port in nginx not able to serve for certain wordpress website

Tags: port, domain, nginx

I don't know if it's related to the domain records pointing rules.

I configured for other website as well and they are fine. I used 8080 as the port for the websites. But for this particular site, every time I input the domain:8080 in the address bar, it automatically cut off the :8080 and leave it only the domain part xxx.com. ( cut off www. at the begin part as well).

Anyone has clue where to look into? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't set the [`port_in_redirect`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#port_in_redirect) tag to `off` in nginx configuration, this may be wordpress fault.

Access the wp-admin website, and go to Settings/General. You may have some difficulties to do that since it will try to redirect you to port 80.

Verify if the `WordPress address (URL)` and `Site address (URL)` have the port specified.